# Best way to shutdown an OSGi Container (specifically equinox)

Tags: osgi, shutdown, equinox

I'm looking for a best practice on shutting down an OSGi container.

Currently we are using a small launcher app which calls EclipseStarter.startup() and installs some core bundles. After that the launcher terminates.

When the test GUI (running as a bundle) is closed it calls a System.exit(0) to shutdown the container, but there must be a more elegant solution than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please, don't use System.exit(0) to shut down an OSGi framework. You should to it by stopping the bundle with the ID 0, the System bundle. This way, you give all bundles a chance to shut down in an orderly manner (e.g. to free resources etc).

The OSGi specification defines the following (Core Specification, R4.x, 4.2.6 Stopping a Framework).

> Shutdown can be initiated by stopping the system bundle, [...] or calling the stop method on the framework object.

In that chapter a detailed description is given what happens when a framework is shut down.

The system bundle resp. the framework object is also defined (chapter 4.6 The System Bundle):

> The system bundle resembles the framework object when a framework is launched, but implementations are not required to use the same object for the framework object and the system bundle. However, both objects must have bundle id 0, same location, and bundle symbolic name.

The OSGi spec is available for free at the OSGi Alliance's website (http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage).

Answer (score 8):

i usually terminate the framework like this:

`bundlecontext.getBundle(0).stop();`

The bundle with id = 0 is the system-bundle

Comment: What is `bundleContext`? Don't put an answer that has the name of your local variable because those of us reading your answer don't have your code to know what type that variable is.

Answer (score 4):

I also use Equinox in an application embedded context and I call stop() on the System Bundle and follow that up with EclipseStarter.shutdown(). You may have to stop all of your bundles.

I've never really been concerned about the bundle shutdown in my application since there is no retained state.

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard way of doing this yet. OSGI will make this part of their standard api in the next release, but I gues that it will take a while before all OSGI containers implement this. Use container specific code for now, but stay away from System.exit().

Regards,

Leen Toelen

Comment: The standard way so far is what I described in my answer. This is the behaviour specified in the OSGi specs, also in the next release 4.2. The next release (4.2.) will include the *optional* Start Level Service that can be used to control the start level of bundles (and the framework).